# JSF 2 - How can I perform an action after a Composite Component child completes an operation?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm still learning to use some of the capabilities of Composite Components in JSF 2. I am experienced with JSF 1.2 development and I have recently read the book "Core Java Server Faces 3rd Edition" by Geary and Horstmann.

What I'm trying to do is create a Composite Component that wraps a file upload component (currently using the PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`). I need to associate the uploaded file with a string-based key on a session-scoped managed bean (to be used later). I am trying to provide the key via an attribute on my Composite Component interface named 'uploadedFileKey'. Here is the interface:

```
<html xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="uploadedFileKey" 
            type="java.lang.String" 
            required="true" />
    </composite:interface>
    ...
</html>
```

The implementation is straightforward and uses the PrimeFaces fileUpload tag as I mentioned earlier. It requires a managed bean with an event handler which I also created based on the sample code from the PrimeFaces showcase webapp. Here is my implementation:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{primeFacesFileUploadController.handler}"
        label="Browse"
        mode="advanced"
        allowTypes="png,gif,jpg" />
</composite:implementation>
```

I'm not going to include the entire controller bean here, but here is the class declaration:

```
@ManagedBean(name="primeFacesFileUploadController")
@RequestScoped
public class PrimeFacesFileUploadController {
    // ...
}
```

The PrimeFaces file upload is not unlike others that I have seen. It uses a custom `Filter` on the Faces Servlet to get access to the uploading data. The actual file upload part works fine and when the upload is successful I have the uploaded file stored in a temp file on my Tomcat server.

**My problem is not knowing how to make my Composite Component take an action after a successful upload. I want my Composite Component to store the `uploadedFileKey` in a `Map` on a particular session-scoped managed bean with the uploaded `File` as the map value. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just pass the key along as a custom component attribute by `<f:attribute>` and let the handler handle it. You can get it in the handler method by `event.getComponent().getAttributes()`.

E.g.

```xml
<composite:implementation>
    <p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{primeFacesFileUploadController.handler}"
        label="Browse"
        mode="advanced"
        allowTypes="png,gif,jpg">
        <f:attribute name="key" value="#{cc.attrs.uploadedFileKey}" />
    </p:fileUpload>
</composite:implementation>
```

with

```
public void handler(FileUploadEvent event) {
    String key = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("key");
    yourSessionBean.getMap().put(key, event.getFile());
}
```